# It is correct to use the word "they" here?

Tags: singular-they

The sentence I've constructed is

> "My boss doesn't need to tell everyone what **they** has to do".

It is correct to use the pronoun "they" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of "they" to reflect "everyone" is correct, however your verb should also reflect this

> My boss doesn't need to tell everyone what they **have** to do

Comment: So in this case 'they' isn't a singular pronoun? I though it could be because i think 'everyone' is singular. Thanks!

Comment: @Iam Toad: As Baby Bear said (in some versions), [Somebody's been sleeping in my bed – and they're still there!](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7ZN-juaDaLIC&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=baby+bear+%22sleeping+in+my+bed+and+they%22&source=bl&ots=mzRslszfRG&sig=rLLKu2N9SO3EgGXApAimUgpFSt0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicxqzs3enNAhWPOsAKHZ4FARcQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=baby%20bear%20%22sleeping%20in%20my%20bed%20and%20they%22&f=false) Even though *semantically*, ***they*** is singular, ***syntactically*** we still use the plural verb form (***are***, not ***is***).

Comment: (Also note that ***everyone*** is *always* syntactically singular.)